# How to reverse the chronological order of pages?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I use [`page.previous` and `page.next`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/) to create links to neighbor pages.

The problem is that the "next" page is the one which is chronologically earlier. In other words, my latest page has one link, `page.next` (linking to an older page)

Is it possible to reverse the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is actually obvious: just use the names the other way round:

- `page.previous` points to the next item, chronologically speaking
- `page.next` points to the previous item, chronologically speaking

I wonder why the names were set up like this (counter-intuitively, since all the posts must be time-stamped).